# Dynamic Lost Focus Event for a text Box throws error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Lost Focus Event Code:

```
public void myTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = ((TextBox)sender).Name;

        string strl = "tbox" + name.Substring(4);
        TextBox text = FindTextBoxByName(strl);

        text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        text.Width = 50;
        text.Height = 40;
    }
```

Event Call:-

```
 myTextBox1j.LostFocus += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(myTextBox_LostFocus);
```

Throws Following Error:-
Cannot implicitly convert type'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LostFocus` event expects a `RoutedEventHandler`, not `EventHandler`.

```
myTextBox1j.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(myTextBox_LostFocus);
```

This should work too:

```
myTextBox1j.LostFocus += myTextBox_LostFocus;
```